# Can I forward a port from a VirtualBox client to the host?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-15.10

(I'm really inexperienced in this area, so apologies if I'm using the wrong terminology, or am asking a simple question - I have searched a lot, but probably due to my not knowing the right words, haven't been able to find a solution.)

Is it possible for me to set up my client machine in VirtualBox (running Ubuntu 15.10) to forward a port to the host machine (running Windows 7)? In other words, if I were to connect, on the client machine, to localhost:1337, I would be connected to the host machine's port 1337.

Comment: Why does it need to be the localhost of the VM? You could simply connect to the VirtualBox host's IP address instead.

Comment: @FrankThomas The guest is Linux. PuTTY only works on Windows.

Comment: @slhck The reason is a bit esoteric: my coworkers do not work in a virtual machine, and we're working on code that connects to something running on our own machines. I'd like not to have to keep an out-of-sync modification of the code to make it connect to my host PC through the network.

Comment: You should look into Docker. It could help provide the abstraction your application clearly requires.

Comment: Docker is definitely on the list of things to look into. The problem in this case for now is that we haven't properly been able to get the application running on Linux yet, and since I'm the only one actually using Linux as a development platform (but on a host Windows machine), getting it to work on Linux (and thus potentially supporting Docker later on) is not that high on the list of priorities.